# Integrating iBeacons into a CoreLocation Indoors Project

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I'm working with CoreLocation to generate an indoor mapping solution where the app will be guiding the user.

Although I'm a little at sea about iBeacons's role in providing precision to CoreLocation indoors.

I've successfully implemented an app where I use iBeacon ranging to determine proximity but can/does iBeacons somehow provide precision to the blue dot which CoreLocation provides to pin point the users current location which somehow I missed?

I'm aware of CoreLocation's shortcomings in terms of precision since it's a nightmare subject to pin point a user's exact location but can iBeacons be used besides ranging to provide precise location data?

Thanks.

Comment: iBeacon out of box does not provide this functionality. However, some iBeacon manufacturers have done work to release micro location in their SDK's. Look into Estimote. They provide complete set up details and have a lot of support on how to use their classes. The downfall is you must use their hardware to work correctly with their code base. It can be done - but it would be more of a brute force way of achieving precise location. Using many beacons even to canvas a small space.

Comment: @MatthewJames Yeah, I know of Estimote. In fact I've their iBeacons; several of them but I forgot to mention that I'm targeting large venues(forgot to mention, my bad, sorry) so I've ruled out that kind of an iBeacon deployment. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: I had some luck implementing a fingerprinting algorithm. It works with any beacon and in theory any device (so possible to port from iOS to android, provided that you understand the logic in the algorithm). At the moment it does not include any heading or relationship to a map but it should not be difficult to add. Open source.  https://github.com/PaoloLongato/open-tagger/tree/github-master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `CoreLocation` to detect beacons, you only get information on how close you are to a Bluetooth beacon with a specific unique identifier.  This does not by itself tell you anything about what latitude or longitude you are at, let alone plot a blue dot more accurately on Apple Maps or any other mapping application.

That said, it is possible to build your own custom navigation app that uses beacon information to tell you where you are indoors.  This, however is not a trivial undertaking.

You can read a blog post I wrote about the effort to [make an indoor navigation app](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/01/13/beacon-navigation-at-the-consumer-electronics-show.html) with over 800 beacons at the huge Consumer Electronics Show in January 2015.

Comment: Thought so. :( Also I should've mentioned that I'm targeting large venues so I've ruled out large iBeacon deployment. My bad. Sorry. Thanks.